# VelocityEnginee throws ResorceNotFoundException when try to use the url.resource.loader

Tags: velocity

I have Required .vm files for the project in remote location.I am sending mail through velocityenginee but it throws ResorceNotFoundException even the file is existed in that location.

http://172.1.2.3//projectName/includes/emails/emailtemplate.vm

when I ran above path directly through the browser it shows file.But when I i try to access file through code throws the below exception

ERROR : org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Unable to find resource 'http://172.1.2.3//projectName/includes/emails/emailtemplate.vm'
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl.loadResource(ResourceManagerImpl.java:452)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl.getResource(ResourceManagerImpl.java:335)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.getTemplate(RuntimeInstance.java:1102)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.getTemplate(RuntimeInstance.java:1077)
    at org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.getTemplate(VelocityEngine.java:528)
    at com.project.InfoFormHandler.getDynamicContentForEmail(ThanksInfoFormHandler.java:288)

Please can anyone help me out in this.Where is the problem or Where I did wrong.

Thanks inadvance

Comment: Can you show us how you did configure Velocity?

Comment: velocityEngine.setProperty("resource.loader", "url");
            velocityEngine.setProperty("url.resource.loader.class","org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.URLResourceLoader");
            velocityEngine.setProperty("url.resource.loader.root","https://172.1.2.3/projectName/");
            velocityEngine.setProperty("url.resource.loader.cache", "false");
            velocityEngine.setProperty("runtime.log.logsystem.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.NullLogSystem"); 
            velocityEngine.init();
    t = velocityEngine.getTemplate("includes/emails/" + templateName);

Comment: It looks correct. You should set the log to something else than the NullLogSystem, and enable debug loglevel to see if there is some more information...

Comment: Any Solution Please?